# With someone's help

Tags: expressions

How should I write the bold parts in an idiomatic way:
We have had many negotiations with the Ministry of X to be able to purchase the raw materials directly from you and eventually produce this medication

> a) **having your help**.
>   b) **with your help**.

I don't know whether there is such an expression in English or not. If there is no such a thing in English, then I would be thankful if you could tell me how should I cite it?

Comment: It is _with your help_, analogous to [With a little help from my friends](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQyCkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DjBDF04fQKtQ%26feature%3Dkp&ei=xKB8U5f_Auq20wXpk4HgCQ&usg=AFQjCNHvKD7VI2tllf6cNnxDBZG1IJ2k3A&sig2=KO_T6SOZhpjmG0tTb2h1mg&bvm=bv.67229260,d.d2k). If it wasn't idiom before the Beatles, they made it so ;)

Comment: @oerkelens thanks for being of help. Just one more question. Can I use the adverb 'monopolistically' instead of 'directly. in my original sentence? I mean: "...purchase the raw materials monopolistically from you and..."?

Comment: A monoploy has negative connotations. I guess _exclusively_ or _in exclusivity_ would sound better.

Comment: I thought so @oerkelens. Thank you very much for this great help. :)

Comment: Even though this has been "answered" can we get a clarification?  Let's call you BUYER, raw supplier SELLER and Ministry of X GOVT. So BUYER has had many negotiations with GOVT to be able to purchase from SELLER to create MEDICATION. At this point, GOVT has given permission to BUYER to buy from SELLER. SELLER has helped you in negotiations with GOVT. And you are writing a "sentence of appreciation" to SELLER (perhaps a thank you or a preface to a proposal/contract), telling SELLER that with SELLER's help, you have SUCCESSFULLY negotiated with GOVT. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As oerkelens tells you, *with your help* is the ordinary idiom here.

I advise you not to use the term *monopolistically* you ask about in your Comment. This is a strongly negative term in most contexts; it signifies domination of an entire market, not a single customer.

What you probably mean is

> We are negotiating with the Ministry to make your firm the exclusive provider of the raw materials ...

Comment: Thanks a million dear @StoneyB. It was really helpful. :)

Comment: Just one more question. Does my version sound correct or I have to modify it like what you wrote above @stoney?

Comment: I think you meant, "We ARE negotiating with ..."

Comment: @A-friend Your version is fine.

Comment: "with your help" is fine, but if this is a formal business communication, I would use "with your assistance".